# Set node degree as a node attribute, using igraph

Tags: r, graph, igraph, statnet

I want to put the degree of each node as a vertex attribute, my code is as follows, but it doesn't work, where the problem could be?

````
degrees <- igraph::degree(graph)
degree<-sort(degrees, decreasing = TRUE)
dat<- as.data.frame(degree)
#max_degree_nodes<-c(226,194,36) 
V(graph)$name[degrees %in% max_degree_nodes]# tweets that have the most number of ties
vertex_attr(graph, "user_name") <- dat$degree
graph```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
set_vertex_attr(
  graph,
  name = "user_name",
  value = degree(graph)
)
```